# Copying Rows of Data to Different Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to coding/JavaScript, so I apologize in advance if this question is (unintentionally) poorly phrased.  I've been searching around and found some similar questions but nothing to solve my issue.

I have a scenario where I have a Workbook with one sheet called "Data" containing records and a column header.  There is another sheet called "Template" containing a fixed template.  I need to duplicate the Template for the number of records in Data (i.e. 5 records of Data will create 4 copies of the original Template).  Next, I need to add the first record in Data to a specific cell range in the original Template, the second record in Data to the same specific cell range in the first Template copy, etc.

I've gotten my script to where I can duplicate the Template sheet and pull all the records into an array, but I haven't been able to figure out how to set the first record to the original Template, the second record to the second Template, etc.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
function duplicate() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data');

var startRow = 2; //first row
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

var StartCol = 1
var LastCol = sheet.getLastColumn()

var numCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow(); // Number of rows to process

var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, StartCol, numRows, numCol);
var data = dataRange.getValues(); 

//Duplicate Sheet based on # of Records 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getSheetByName("Template"); 
for (i=1;i<numRows;++i) s.copyTo(ss).setName("Template "+i);

//A bad attempt at trying to add the records to each template copy
var nextSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template "+i);
nextSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,numRows,numCol).setValues(data[0+1]);
}
```

'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like each data record[row] to have its own sheet, based on a `Template`, with the single record inserted into the same cell range for each record's individual sheet?

```
function duplicate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  // Get the Template sheet
  var template = ss.getSheetByName("Template"); 

  var startRow = 2; //first row
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var StartCol = 1;
  var LastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();

  var numCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow(); // Number of rows to process

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, StartCol, numRows, numCol);
  var data = dataRange.getValues(); 

  // The constant single column range to insert the data record into
  var data_insert_range = sheet.getRange("C14:C22").getA1Notation();

  // For each data record create a new sheet based on the template
  // and insert into a pre-set range
  data.forEach(function (e,i) {
    var nextSheet = ss.insertSheet("Template Copy " + i, {template: template});
    // Map each col of the record into it's own row
    var dataRowIntoCol = e.map(function (c) { return [c] });
    // Insert record into the desired column
    nextSheet.getRange(data_insert_range).setValues(dataRowIntoCol);
  });
}
```

Instead of using the template to both copy from and overwriting data, I would suggest keeping the `Template` pure and create new sheets for writing data from it. If not, just place your `copyTo()` back in place of the `insertSheet()` and it will work that way as well

**edit:** Updated code to reflect clarified range/data information

Comment: Hi random-parts, this works really well but I encountered a new issue.  The data_insert_range value sets to A4:I4.  I actually need the data to populate in each new sheet in C14:C22.  I tried modifying the data_insert_range to C14:C22 but receive the following error: "Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 9 ".  I assume I need to transpose my array elements but can't figure out how to actually do it (and have the whole script continue to work).

Comment: What is the range, in A1Notation, of one of the data records?

Comment: "Data!A2:I2" is the first record, with the second in "Data!A3:I3".  "Data!A1:I1" is the header row.  Each record would be inserted into each template in C14:C22.

Comment: Updated code to change the record row into a column & insert into desired range. The `data_insert_range` would have to be updated if your data ends up having more or less than 9 columns at some point. The error "Incorrect range height" meant that the `setValues()` was trying to insert a record with 9 rows

Comment: Thank you!  I assume ideally I should set getRange to the start row/column instead of C14:C22, but this works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't sure exactly what you wanted but I think this will give you a boost in a positive direction.

```
function duplicate() {

var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('Data');

var startRow = 2; //first row
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

var StartCol = 1
var LastCol = sheet.getLastColumn()

var numCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-startRow+1; // Number of rows to process

var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, StartCol, numRows, numCol);
var data = dataRange.getValues(); 

//Duplicate Sheet based on # of Records 

var s = ss.getSheetByName("Template"); 
for (i=0;i<numRows;++i) 
{
  s.copyTo(ss).setName("Template " + Number(i+1));
  s.getRange(startRow,startCol,numRows,numCol).setValues(data);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting a getValues(object) error even after correcting the StartCol case and didn't know where to go from there since I'm not sure why it isn't reading data.  The other answer by (random-parts) is duplicating sheets/inserting data as I need to, but it's just inserting it into the wrong location.

Comment: Oops. I had getValues() instead of setValues().  That may make a difference.  But your original code was not that helpful in figuring out what you wanted.  So you'll probably have to tweak things a bit.